# How to know Users App Time Information in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-android

**So, I want to build an app where I can track the users' time spent in a particular app. For example, he spends 3 hours on Twitter, 2 hours on Netflix, and so on. Is there any way to find this out? Or, the only way is to ask the user itself about his/her activity?
Please help!**

Comment: did you find something for iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [app_usage package](https://pub.dev/packages/app_usage):

> Application usage stats for Android only. Note that the stats are only precise down to a daily basis. This is a limitation from Google's implementation, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will look into it!